# Copy range indicated by inputbox

Tags: vba, excel, range, inputbox

I am looking to a model which can copy a particular range in an excel sheet to a new sheet. Currently I have five columns. The first column is the year. I want to indicate, for example with an `inputbox`which year should be copied. In column B, the weeks of the year are indicated. In the columns C until E, specific data is recorded. As a result, my sheet look like this:

```
Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D   ColE
Year    Week    Amount  time    forecast
2000    1       368     2000w1  400
2000    2       8646    2000w2  8500
until...
2014    52      46546   2014w52 47000
```

With the input box, I want to indicate that the year 2014 should be copied to the next sheet. Until now I wrote/compiled the following macro:

```
Sub Copy_year()
    Dim Forecastyear As String
    Dim Rng As Range

    Forecastyear = InputBox("Enter a year to forecast")

    If Trim(Forecastyear) <> "" Then
        With Sheets(2).Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=Forecastyear, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If

    'Range(ActiveCell, RC[52,4]).Select
End Sub
```

This select the first cell which contains the year value. I want to select the full 5 columns for the row with the selected cell and the next 51 weeks (together 52 weeks). How can I select all that data?

Comment: Is the data always sorted?

Comment: Yes, The data is always the year chronological, next the data is sorted by the second column where the week is chronological.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
Sub Copy_year()
    Dim Forecastyear As String
    Dim Rng As Range

    Forecastyear = InputBox("Enter a year to forecast")

    If Trim(Forecastyear) <> "" Then
        With Sheets(2)
            For Each cell In .Range("A:A")
                If cell.Value = Forecastyear Then'find first occurrence of year
                    Set Rng = cell
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            .Range(Rng.Address).Resize(52, 5).Select'resize for 52 rows and 5 columns
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

What are you going to do with it now? just selecting is rather inefficient in terms of cpu time

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works very well. However, I first had to define cell in advance. Did you forgot that, or do you have other settings so you do not need to define?  Anyway, thank you very much for your effort. I will use this to copy the selected area to copy to the next sheet. In the next sheet, I will review the forecastingsmethod which I used. To do this, I made several other macros.

Comment: I was going to post a similar way of doing it. I believe this is the easiest way. Although once the Rng is found, you could just apply the resize to your own rng @vba_interested, because Find is faster than that loop. If you have less than 100 items it shouldn't make a visible difference, though.

Comment: I didnt have "option explicit" on when I made above so I ddnt have to declare it but declaring it would be better. Glad it worked for you

Comment: @DavidGM Really if you wanted to be really quick you would read it into an array or a dictionary

Comment: Thanks all. Now I have the next question: Is it possible to use more than one year?

Comment: as in search for 2001, 2004 and 2014? need much more detail than that. really you should start another question as this has been answered